# Trigger one tab only per time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my code here, I want to show a story for each tab has its own `text` and `Background Music`, The problem here is when i open tab `part1` and open the `music`, then move to tab `part2`, The `music` from `part1` is still active, And if i started all `tabs` `music` all the 3 `BGMs` will run at the same time, How can i keep 1 `tab` only active?

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#part1" role="tab">Part 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part2" role="tab">Part 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part3" role="tab">Part 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="part1" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 1</b> <br> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> 
        BGM: <br>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="part2" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 2</b> <br> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> 
        BGM: <br>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="part3" role="tabpanel">
        <b>Story Part 3</b> <br> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> 
        BGM: <br>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to implement another function that stops the music, in order to call this when you're switching tabs.

edit:  You may have to manually start each audio element when switching tabs

```
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        musicStop();
        $(this).tab('show')
    })

function musicStop(){
    //stop all audio playing
    $.each($('audio'), function () {
        $(this).stop();
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, Is there a way to shut the entire tab?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle and link to it in your question?  It's unclear to me how you're expecting it to work, and what it looks like now.

Comment: I made the snippet, My problem is that If i started Tab1 Music then moved to Tab2, Tab1 is still active and the music plays, And i want to turn all tabs off except the selected tab.

Comment: And that's what I've tried to help with in my answer. So what do you think the problem still is?

Comment: I tried your Javascript function, Didn't work, Everything still working at the same time, Even if i switched tabs

Comment: It doesn't look like your click event is even firing.  Are you wrapping the event handler assignment in $(document).ready()?  Also, where is the element with id 'myTab'?

Comment: I just took the code directly from Bootstrap, Even if i removed `#myTab a` the script would still work, And the code is working yeah.

Comment: Can i refresh the previous selected tab?